# LeadLander formalyze_init.js Javascript external file

Tags: javascript, forms

I just came across this 2 script files that i see some websites are

http://formalyzer.com/formalyze_call.js and 
http://formalyzer.com/formalyze_init.js

Something looks strange with these scripts and there is not much information available about these scripts online. Can anyone tell what they do and is it good to use them in your website.

Thanks
Aaqib

Answer (score 2):

They are used by a company called LeadLander, and they are used to create sales leads for the website owner based on data obtained by visitors to the website.  These two particular javascript files are for tracking data entered into "contact us" forms.

To use them, you'd need to have an account with LeadLander as you also need to set your id.  Additionally, you'll need to have an account to receive and review the reports they generate.

Comment: Thanks SergioL i figured that out but can you tell me one thing. if on my website i have privacy policy for storing the data from contact us form then using Lead Lender is a revocation of that policy because i am passing the details to some other company which i said i won't... Am i correct?

Comment: That's a good question.  They are aggregating the contact data for you, so the data IS being sent to a 3rd party.  I think this is a gray area...it's your data being stored off-site, yes.  I don't believe LeadLander has rights to that data for their own purposes, so it's still yours alone, but I don't know what the legal ramifications are...I'm just a developer. :-)

Comment: Yeah same here i am a developer too... But i think if we using LeadLander on our website we need to mention it in privacy policy. :)) Anyways Thanka!!!

Comment: There's actually a little blurb on the LeadLander site that recommends updating your privacy policy.  So you are absolutely right about making that change.